# Azure Datafactory can't handle empty json array in blob

Tags: azure, etl, azure-data-factory

in azure data factory dataset, using the copy activity to load json blob to sqldb, when the json blob is an empty array "[]" the copy activity gets stuck with error.

```
{
    "errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorTypeInSchemaTableNotSupported,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Failed to get the type from schema table. This could be caused by missing Sql Server System CLR Types.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.InvalidCastException,Message=Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Type'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "BP_acctset_Blob2SQL",
    "details": []
}
```

Comment: Can you add a Get MetaData activity and get the size of the json file, then you juge if the size > 2 to exec the following copy activity?

Comment: Hi, @WindRider. If my answer is helpful for you, please accept(mark) it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members.

Answer (score -1):

1. Use Get Metadata to get the file size.
   [image]
2. Use if condition to juge if the size is greater than 2. If true then exec copy activity.
   [image]